# Bash/Shell: How to add to history without removing the callee history function

Tags: bash, shell, input-history

```
history -s
```

^ Command will add to history. However, it will also not allow the callee function to remain in the history.

To clarify with example:

When we have a function:

```
history.demo() {

  echo "args: $@"

  history -s "echo HI WORLD"
}
export -f history.demo;
```

And call this function in terminal

```
history.demo 1 a
```

What I would like to see saved in the history is

```
history.demo 1 a
echo HI WORLD
```

However, what I do see is only

```
echo HI WORLD
```

How can we get the original and the add-on into bash history?

Comment: This just isn't how it works. The bash documentation defines history as "the list of commands previously **typed**". In your example, `echo HI WORLD` was not typed.

Comment: If you're already doing efforts to rewrite the history, why not just do `history -s "$(basename '$0') "$@"` before the other `history -s`?

Comment: @r2evans history -s "${FUNCNAME[0]} $@" appears to be doing the trick thank you for the pointer!

Comment: Can I ask for what a history-revisionist function is useful?

Comment: @r2evans My use case I have a FUNCTION. FUNCTION is called with arguments. Now I want to call this function repeatedly with different arguments in succession. Rewriting history allows me to have the following saved in the history. FUNCTION {args}, FUNCTION. 

Instead of what actually happened is FUNCTION {args}. That way a single up arrows gets me to the place I want instead of 2 up arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following is doing the trick (thank you r2evans@ for the pointer)

```
history.demo() {
  echo "args: $@"

  history -s "${FUNCNAME[0]} $@"
  history -s "echo HI WORLD"
}
export -f history.demo;
```